# I can not improve nextPermutation method in the TSP problem

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, brute-force

Good,

I have advanced the problem of the traveler agent (TSP) in java by brute force, but I have a problem in the method "nextPermutation". I assume that the inverse of the routes are identical, therefore the cost of my code will be: n!/2. I have done several paper tests exchanging the indexes in various ways and always enter an infinite loop.

The idea is the following: If I have the following vector:

```
Int[] array = {0,1,2,3};
```

The method "nextPermutation" should generate me a list such that:

> 0123 = 3210
>
> 2031 = 1302
>
> 0231 = 1320
>
> 0321 = 1230
>
> 0312 = 2130
>
> 1032 = 2301
>
> 0132 = 2310
>
> 1203 = 3021
>
> 2103 = 3012
>
> 2013 = 3102
>
> 0213 = 3120
>
> 1023 = 3201

It is indifferent the left or right route, both are totally valid, in addition you can see that the total of permutations is 4! / 2 = 12.

My code is n!, but i want n!/2:

```
   public static boolean nextPermutation (int[] v) {

        int i = v.length - 1;
        while (i > 0 && v[i - 1] >= v[i]) {
            i--;
        }
        if (i <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int j = v.length - 1;
        while (v[j] <= v[i - 1]) {
            j--;
        }

        swap(v, i, j);

        return true;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] v, int i, int j) {
        int aux = v[i - 1];
        v[i - 1] = v[j];
        v[j] = aux;

        j = v.length - 1;
        while (i < j) {
            aux = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = aux;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

With this code I generate all the permutations and I end in the case that the vector is {3,2,1,0}, but I want to improve the method and avoid calculating the cases in which it be inverse. For example, it is the same to go from California to Florida and then to Texas to go from Texas to Florida and then to California, therefore that calculation is unnecessary.

I hope I have been clear, a greeting and thank you!

Comment: Since you're iterating all permutations, you will get e.g. `0123 = 3210` and `3210 = 0123`, so to remove one of them, only return permutations where right side is larger than left side. That way you remove half the results. It would mean that you'd get `1302 = 2031` as a result, not `2031 = 1302` like you showed, but does that matter?

Comment: @Andreas The only element that meets the right side is larger than the left side is `3210`,do not?

Comment: Any reason for not wanting to use a library for this? See combinatorics: http://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/, or Guava's Collection2, or Apache Commons Collection (PermutationIterator).

Comment: Normally California-Florida-Texas and Texas-Florida-California are not the same. The preconditions and postconditions are different. If you ignore the conditions,  Florida-Texas-California should also be the same.

Comment: @user58697 if we talk about distance traveled, it should be the same in reverse. You travel the same distance in going from your home to school, that from school to your home.

Comment: @user58697 my algorithm calculates the distance traveled of each route and keeps the minimum. Now that I think about it, I could start only from a city like that, for example if I have 4 cities ABCD, I would always start in city A and it would be a cost problem (n-1)! Do you think it can work?

Comment: @postgresqlx12 Your code generates 24 combinations. When you then reverse each to build 24 pairs, 12 of those pairs will have right value > left value. Skipping those 12 combinations will leave you with 12 combinations, which covers the 12 you show, though some will be flipped from what you show.